# Pythonocc Import error Dll load failed

Tags: python-2.7, 3d, cad

I am getting started with pythonocc i have tried to import some modules and return with the following errors

```
   `     Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        from OCC.gp import *
        File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OCC\gp.py", line 28, in <module>
        _gp = swig_import_helper()
         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OCC\gp.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_gp', fp, pathname, description)
         ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
   `
```

i am using windows 64 bit python 2.7.3 32bit and pythonocc 0.5 all in one

What is the solution to the above probelm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install pythonocc 0.6 from this link http://code.google.com/p/pythonocc/ this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have 64 bit python, it can struggle to load 32 bit Dll's.

Try this [link](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1010140)

I recommend getting a 32 bit distribution of python, this should solve your problem

Comment: i do have a 32 bit python installed

Answer (score 0):

At the following link you can find pythonOCC for Python 2.7:
http://code.google.com/p/pythonocc/downloads/list

Link was tested on 07/10/14